# How to print lines from a file in reverse order

Tags: c

I am trying to print a file in reverse order. I am using arrays to save each lines data. So far I was able to print every line in a normal order.

index is the number of lines I am referring to and FuncIndex the same thing but has been declared again in the function.

```
file = fopen("../quotes.data","r");
while (NumOfField == 8) {
    NumOfField = fscanf(file,"%d,%c,%d,%d,%c,%c,%lf,%lf", &quote[index], &roomletter[index], &length[index], &width[index], &paint[index], &ceiling[index], &cost[index], &setup_cost[index]);
    index++;
}
index--;
fclose(file);
```

In Function:

```
int FuncIndex;
for (FuncIndex = 0; FuncIndex <= index; FuncIndex++) {
    printf("\n%5d   %1c   %3d    %3d    %1c      %1c    %8.2lf %6.2lf", quote[FuncIndex], roomletter[FuncIndex], length[FuncIndex], width[FuncIndex], paint[FuncIndex], ceiling[FuncIndex], cost[FuncIndex], setup_cost[FuncIndex]);
}
```

Now I tried changing the for loop to:

```
for (FuncIndex = index; FuncIndex >= 0; FuncIndex--) >
```

But the output prints empty. Although when I change the 0 to any number, that corresponding line gets printed.

The output That prints is:

```
Quote Room Length Width Paint Ceiling     Cost  Setup
===== ==== ====== ===== ===== =======  =======  =====
531   A    10     10    b      n       96.00 100.00
531   B    15     15    b      n      144.00   0.00
531   C    20     20    b      n      192.00   0.00
```

I am looking to get this output reversed like:

```
Quote Room Length Width Paint Ceiling     Cost  Setup
===== ==== ====== ===== ===== =======  =======  =====
531   C    20     20    b      n      192.00   0.00
531   B    15     15    b      n      144.00   0.00
531   A    10     10    b      n       96.00 100.00
```

Please excuse me if I putted the output in the code section because then the formatting would change

Thank you.

Comment: 0) Welcome to Stack Overflow! 1) Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such. We'll still help, but we'll provide answers that are better tailored to your needs. 2) Please pick one language keyword -- either C or C++. 3) What do you mean by "reverse order"? Please provide a sample input and output.

Comment: btw, why don't you use array of `struct`s instead of parallel arrays ?

Comment: I am totally new to C and barely know about arrays, would you please tell me what does each do?

Comment: See also http://www.koders.com/c/fid7BF314A5F0B3A30EADEADCD93C79D5771191FF2C.aspx O:-) (OK, that's overkill, but…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the answer to my question:

the EOF was the trick

```
for (FuncIndex = index; FuncIndex != EOF; FuncIndex--)
```

Basically, in here you are saying that whatever the number of index is (Number of Lines) put it in the FuncIndex and then one by one (from the highest number) check each line until its not the end of line anymore.

Comment: `The EOF was the trick` - the EOF is incorrect.  `EOF` stands for "End of File," and is a special delimiter used by some C-functions to indicate that you have finished reading the entire file.  You are not reading from a file here, so the `EOF` doesn't belong.  What you want is `FuncIndex >= 0`.  (Un?)fortunately for you, `EOF` is usually defined as `-1`, so for most systems your code will still give the same result.  However, it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: If you take a closer look at my code you will see that I am reading a file and also I have posted an answer because it worked and I don't wanna say if its correct or not because I don't even know if this is the right way of doing it, but it worked that was my concern, I don't know how but it did.

Comment: condition `FuncIndex != EOF` is exactly the same as `FuncIndex != -1` and in your context is the same as `FuncIndex >= 0`. At least replace `EOF` with `-1`, because your condition has nothing to do with `EOF` (end of file) flag

Comment: b.t.w, have you tried code from my answer ? If it somehow doesn't fit your needs, feel free to ask and I'll change it

Comment: Oo okey. yes for sure, i respect your answer. Its excactly the same. but i just felt confortable with EOF because I was already dealing with files. anyways I do appreciate your answer.

Comment: **1.** no need to apologize :). **2.** However, note that your `FuncIndex` loop doesn't have anything to do with files. It's iterating trough arrays. EOF (end of file) is at least confusing in this context (the most clear code possible is really *really* **REALLY** underestimated by beginner programmers). **3.** If your program doesn't work with `FuncIndex >= 0`, but works with `FuncIndex != EOF` than most likely, you have a bug which you just have hidden somehow. Be it a part of production code, you would sorely regret this later. I tell you, you want to learn such things easy way

Comment: I just found our that it also works with FuncIndex >= 0. I think I may have tried in a different way, but anyway thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post all your code (however, try to reduce it to minimum). This works for me:

File input.txt

```
530 A
531 B
532 C
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_LINES 50

int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    int NumOfField = 2;
    int index = 0;
    char roomLetter[ MAX_LINES ];
    int  quote     [ MAX_LINES ];

    file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    while ( NumOfField == 2 ) {
        NumOfField = fscanf(file,"%d %c\n", &quote[index], &roomLetter[index]);
        index++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    index--;

    for(; index >=0; index-- )
        printf( "%d %c\n", quote[index], roomLetter[index] );

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```