# C language how to scan file with integers in reverse order?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, scanf

I have a small file containing numbers, separated by new lines/spaces.
I am looking for a way to scan the file , but in reverse.

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5 1025
Output: 1025 5 4 3 2 1
```

Attention! in the following code, I need to modify the scanf. I need to leave printf unchanged! I don't need to transform 1024 into 4201, the integers remain unchanged. Only their order changes.

Code:

```
while (fscanf(input,"%d", &b) && !feof(input)) {printf("%d",b);}
```

Comment: Read the numbers into an array and print the array in the reverse order.

Comment: Either you do difficult back-seeking or you read it into an array and print that in reverse order.

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong. If an input error occurs, your code goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394155/how-to-print-lines-from-a-file-in-reverse-order).

Comment: [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @pmg what would be correct then?

Comment: Testing the return value of `fscanf` like a sane person: `while (fscanf(input, "%d", &b) == 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a big enough stack?

```
void printreverse(FILE *f) {
    int n;
    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &n) != 1) return;
    printreverse(f); // recursive call
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

https://ideone.com/1jejpM

Comment: I was going to suggests reversing through recursion, and here it is

Comment: `printf("%d", n);` -> `printf("%d ", n);`, output will look better.

Comment: @Jabberwocky OP said: "I need to leave printf unchanged!"

Comment: @pmg yes, but in his sample output  there _are_ spaces between numbers. OK, not the first time requirements in questions are contradictory.